# Could not autowire. No beans of 'AuthenticationProvider' type found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I cant autowire an AuthenticationProvider Spring framework instance in my SecurityConfig class. This is strange as I have included the necessary import and the UserDetailsService (another Spring Framework class) can be autowired without any issues. This is my code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.RememberMeServices
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    companion object {
        private const val REMEMBER_ME_KEY = "basdrwerdadev$#@safasfewrahl"
    }

    @Autowired private lateinit var authenticationProvider: AuthenticationProvider
    @Autowired private lateinit var userDetailsService: UserDetailsService
    ...
```

Maybe I am missing a dependency? I have added the Spring security dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First 2 things I would check are:
i)  is your custom authentication provider annotated as a Service/Component (i.e. can spring see and manage it?) 
ii) Does it extend spring's AuthenticationManager interface?

Comment: My authentication provider is not custom. I use the one provided by Spring.

Comment: Spring's AuthenticationProvider is an interface provided by Spring that you can implement with your own custom logic. I would try changing the AuthenticationProvider to any of the various implementations provided by spring. If that works you can choose the one that fits your project best, or even implement the interface yourself